# Adding infinite scroll to my table in partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table in my partial view,

```
<table id="tblClaimSearch" class="display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="ChkboxClaimHeader" name="ChkboxClaimHeader" value="false"/></th>
            <th>Claim #</th>
            <th>Client Name</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Deduction</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Status</th>                       
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    @if (Model.Claims != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.Claims)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbox-claim"/></td>
                <td>@item.ClaimNumber</td>
                <td>@item.Client</td>
                <td>@item.Amount</td>
                <td>@item.Deduction</td>
                <td>@item.Type</td>
                <td>@item.Status</td>
            </tr>                                   
        }
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I wish to add infinite scroll to this table, currently I have number pagination which I got as default from bootstrap..

Comment: Have you tried anything to accomplish what you want?

Comment: I tried this..                                                             $(window).scroll(function () { if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) { alert("Scroll is working"); } });, It is taking for the whole window(i.e, my main window)...I need the scroll only for my partial view

Comment: Out of scope FLAG. Never write JS dirrectly in your Views. It's worst practice when we talk about ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You'll ideally want to debounce your scroll for performance if you are doing calculations every scroll as the event is fired many many times every second (as you'll see if you console log). You'll also want to cache your selectors into variables outside the event handler (i.e. $(window).scroll) scope.

But performance aside you'll need this part:

```
@if (Model.Claims != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.Claims)
    {
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbox-claim"/></td>
            <td>@item.ClaimNumber</td>
            <td>@item.Client</td>
            <td>@item.Amount</td>
            <td>@item.Deduction</td>
            <td>@item.Type</td>
            <td>@item.Status</td>
        </tr>                                   
    }
}
```

as a partial that you inject in via a get ajax request. You'll pass through the starting index as a parameter from the JS (which you increment every time you trigger the function of scrolling to the bottom) and return some HTML. If it is the case that you return the whole result set up front but don't want to render it all then you would store that snippet as a partial in memory and populate it from your collection of models bit by bit in say blocks of 10.

I'm not sure what this templating language is

```
@if (Model.Claims != null)
```

but i'm pretty sure Bootstrap won't be able to help you accomplish what you are after, is something custom.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's Razor. http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/

Comment: So yeh as it is server side, stick that partial in a separate file and call it in via ajax. You will be using jquery most likely as you have bootstrap, so use the $.get method and call it in and use the append jQuery method to stick it in the tbody blocks at a time

Comment: Did you manage to sort it @RazvanDumitru ? Is the answer correct? Thanks, Alex

Comment: Was @Michael Philips's problem, not mine.